# Why does Char(1) change to Char(3) when copying over an Oracle DBLINK?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, dblink

I have 2 databases, and **I want to transport an existing table containing a CHAR column from database A to database B.**

Database A is Oracle 9i, has encoding WE8ISO8859P1, and contains a table "foo" with at least 1 column of type CHAR(1 char).  I can not change the table on database A because it is part of a third party setup.

Database B is my own Oracle 10g database, using encoding AL32UTF8 for all kinds of reasons, and I want to copy foo into this database.

I setup a database link from database B to database A. Then I issue the following command:

*create table bar as select * from #link#.foo;*

The data gets copied over nicely, but when I check the types of the columns, I notice that CHAR(1 char) has been converted into CHAR(3 char), and when querying the data in database B, it is all padded with spaces.

I think somewhere underwater, Oracle confuses it's own bytes and chars. CHAR(1 byte) is different from CHAR(1 char) etc. I've read about all that.

**Why does the datatype change into a padded CHAR(3 char) and how do I stop Oracle from doing this?**

*Edit: It seems to have to do with transfering CHAR's between two specific patchlevels of Oracle 9 and 10. It looks like it is really a bug. as soon as I find out I'll post an update. Meanwhile: don't try to move CHAR's between databases like I described. VARCHAR2 works fine (tested).*

*Edit 2: **I found the answer and posted it here:** [Why does Char(1) change to Char(3) when copying over an Oracle DBLINK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253971/why-does-char1-change-to-char3-when-copying-over-an-oracle-dblink#263467)
Too bad I can not accept my own answer, because my problem is solved.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is caused by the way Oracle (mis)handles character conversions between different character sets based on the original column length definition. When you define the size of a character type column in bytes, Oracle does not know how to do a conversion and bodges it. **The solution is to always define the length of a character type in characters**.

For a more in-depth explanation of the problem and how I figured this out have a look at
http://www.rolfje.com/2008/11/04/transporting-oracle-chars-over-a-dblink/

Answer (score 2):

YOu need to learn the difference between the WE8ISO8859P1 NLS (which stores characters in one byte) and the AL32UTF8 which stores characters in up to four bytes. You will need to spend some quality time with the Oracle National Language Support (NLS) [Documentation](http://www.cs.umbc.edu/help/oracle8/server.815/a67789/ch2.htm#745). Oracle automatically does the conversion through the database link, in an attempt to be helpful.

Try the following from your SQL prompt:

```
ALTER SESSION NLS_NCHAR WE8ISO8859P1 
create table bar as select * from #link#.foo;
```

Comment: Yeh NLS is a pain. I bet you've had your share of quiet evenings with the docs. ;-)

Comment: I would understand if the original type was "1 char" and it got changed to "3 byte" or "4 bytes".  By why would "1 char" be changed to "3 char"?

Comment: I've been reading about this for 32 hours now. So I agree with Dave, "1 char" -> "3 bytes" I understand. But "1 char" -> "3 chars" and adding padding is plain wrong. If I set the NLS_NCHAR, I would set it to the NLS of the LOCAL database. Instead, you chose to set the remote NLS. Why?

Comment: Funny addition: Setting the NLS_CHAR in the session is for some reason impossible through jdbc. I tried the NLS_CHAR in SquirrelSQL, to no avail. I think online Oracle documentation one big cross-reference maze which does not contain clear and helpful text.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would try is Creating the table NOT as a CTAS but with a list of column definitions and try to perform an insert of the first few thousand rows. If that didn't succeed then it would be very clear why... and you'd have quick confirmation that Thomas Low is dead on accurate.